# What are the big stars after leaving a station?

Tags: rebel-galaxy-outlaw

As you can see in the picture below, there are 3 big white stars (never mind my CPU temperature) pointed by the green arrows. What does those stars mean?

[image: stars picture]

Answer (score 2):

Those represent your wanted level. By performing acts against the law (going full pirate) your wanted level will increase, and with it, your likelihood to be attacked in that system.

Comment: How far is the scale? 0 to 10? 1 to 5?

Comment: I don't own the game so find myself unable to check. Assuming it's simple to make a new save file, you could try yourself.